# How to run a function in a separate thread

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

I'm working on a project that involves reading stuff on an automation server and storing that in a database.

Currently the whole thing is implemented to work synchronously, and I want to make this Asynchronous

I have a big method that calls a whole bunch of API over which I have no control, and that are not Async

My goal is to wrap all this in an asynchronous call

So I made a new method:

```
Public Async Function ReadAsync() As Task
    While reading
        ReadNext()
    End While
End Function
```

Problem is: I get a warning saying that my function should include an "Await". But I don't really have anything to await. I want to read the next iteam as soon as readnext is done.

Do I have to have this await call? Is there a way to await nothing? Is this the correct way to wrap my method and make it Asyncrhonous?

Comment: That's not an asynchronous method. That's a plain-old synchronous method with the `async` keyword that generates a warnng saying it will execute synchronously

Comment: Maybe I don't understand async correctly. My objective is to run that loop in another thread to offload my UI. Perhaps I should just consider System.Trheading instead

Comment: To start somethin in the background you call `Await Task.Run` and pass the method/lambda/delegate to execute to it. It's *Task.Run* that will run the job in a new task/thread. `Await` will await for it to finish asynchronously, ie without blocking the main thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function-Level Async does not any magic by itself. If you want to execute method in backgroud thread, you can execute it in [ThreadPool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx). This can be done following way:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf Read)
```

In that case, your Function signature should following:

```
Public Sub Read(stateInfo as Object)
    While reading
        ReadNext()
    End While
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know about Parallel.For

However that's not what I'm looking for. What I want is for ReadNext() to happen one after another, but I want the call to ReadAsync to be running parallel to the rest of my application, so that the UI remains functional

Comment: Ok, then you can fire new Thread to be executed in ThreadPool. You can see good example [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool(v=vs.110).aspx). I modified my answer.

Comment: `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` seems kind of out-of-date - wouldn't it be more accurate to use `Async` `Await` `TaskCompletionSource` `Task.Run` etc.? Might be that I'm just not used to using QueueUserWorkItem though.

Comment: Eventually, I opted for this:

    `Public Sub NextRecord()
        Dim myThread As Thread
        myThread = New Thread(AddressOf ReadRecord)
        myThread.Start()
    End Sub`

Which seems to work fine. I've also used Interlocked.Exchange to ensure coherence of data